# Строение таблицы в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных, таблицы

делаю периодически БД(Mysql) для интернет-магазинов, новостных сайтов и т.д. . Хочу задать вопрос по поводу их построения, приведу пример. У меня есть таблица с одеждой, у каждого товара есть по несколько своих раскрасок и размеров, их я записываю в отдельное поле разделяя "|"
[image: Строение таблицы]

Но я понимаю что это очень топорно и неэлегантно, подскажите как я могу это исправить. Как это делать более правильно и красивее?

Comment: В данном конкретном случае напрашивается таблица разновидностей товаров в которой насколько записей id "товара" = 50, цвет и собственный id записи (хотя я бы ее считал настоящей таблицей товаров), на складе то лежит именно конкретная разновидность, значит товар то она. И вторая таблица id разновидности, количество (а возможно даже не количество, а много записей с + и - движение этого товара по складу). А вообще картинка товара вполне может то же переехать в таблицу разновидностей, что бы можно было показывать конкретно красные или синие и там могут еще появится атрибуты ...

Comment: Но вообще возможно структура вообще древовидная, потому что "красные найки Air" это еще не товар который на складе. Возможно используется вот эта же самая таблица что на картинке, только в ней есть запись "найки", потом отдельно "красные найки" в которых есть ссылка на "найки" и третья запись "красные найки 41 размера", которые ссылаются соответственно на "красные найки". А количество на складе в любом случае отдельно, это не свойство товара, это вообще его движение, иначе у вас будет масса проблем если складов станет более 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более правильно нормализовать данные. Более подробнее об этом можно почитать конечно же в интернете, на эту тему полно статей. Например, на [Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/193756/)

По поводу организации хранения товаров в реляционных БД, то тут очень много подходов, это отдельная большая тема, просто так ее тут не опишешь. Лучше, конечно же, почитать про это)
Хранить следует сами товары и свойства к ним отдельно, причем они могут быть множественными и иметь разные типы.
Например: Таблица товаров, таблица свойств товаров и его тип, таблица значений свойств товаров и таблица привязки свойства к товарам.
В отдельных случаях делают денормализацию данных для оптимизации, но это уже другая история.